# How to correctly pass MKCoordinateRegion to a function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkcoordinateregion

I would like to pass the `MKCoordinateRegion` to a function which in turn sends it to server for analysis.

However I'm unable to pass it to the function due to a syntax error `Expected a type`.

I'm guessing it's because `MKCoordinateRegion` is a `C` struct, and `C` structs can't be passed as arguments to methods in `Objective-C`.

What is the correct way to pass this information to a methods, as a single variable?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I've found the solution. For some reason xcode didn't recognized dependencies for that specific .h file. I had to place `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` in the .h file, even though it is already specified in the prefix.psh and it's recognized and used in other files... maybe a bug in xcode...

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: I've found the solution. For some reason xcode didn't recognized dependencies for that specific .h file. I had to place #import <MapKit/MapKit.h> in the .h file, even though it is already specified in the prefix.psh and it's recognized and used in other files... maybe a bug in xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you put asterisk after typing MKCoordinateRegion?
This code works:

```
- (void)setRegion
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = self.latitudeFromServer;
    region.center.longitude = self.longitudeFromServer;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.112872;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.112872;

    [self sendRegion:region]; //sending to method!
}   

- (void)sendRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region
{
    NSLog(@"upload region to server");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I do it, and it gives me the error. I'm not sure if it's related, but my project uses ARC...

Comment: `- (NSArray *) getSearchResults:(NSString *)searchQuery exploreIn:(NSString *)area byCategory:(NSString *)category withinRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)aRegion currentLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)currentLocation;` It points are the MKCoordinateRegion

Answer (score 0):

I use NSData to pass the MKCoordinateRegion to a delegate method and all works fine (also do similar to pass MKMapRect)

Convert to NSData:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapPointLoc, 2000, 2000);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&region length:sizeof(MKCoordinateRegion)];
[self.delegate mapViewUpdateRegion:data];
```

and to read from NSData:

```
- (void)mapViewUpdateRegion:(NSData *)regionData{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    [regionData getBytes:&region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```